# Uttanka was student of Gautama or Veda?

Tags: mahabharata

In [Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01004.htm) of Mahabharata it is detailed that Uttanka was disciple of Veda, who was disciple of Dhaumya. Here the story explains how he tried to get the earring from king Paushya's wife; Takskaka takes away the ring and so on.

In [Ashwameda parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14057.htm), Uttanka is disciple of Gautama. Ahalya asks for the ring from king Saudasha's wife.

From the stories of ring, it sounds like same person. But the preceptors are different; kings are different; Naga who took ring is different (Takshaka Vs Airawata's family).

Any other references to confirm which of these is correct? Or, explanation on why the differences?

Comment: It says same race, not family or descent. It is possible Takshaka ended up in the same race despite not being born in Airavata's lineage. This happens a lot in scripture such as all the Manus turning human, despite all coming from different lineages.